# Can i set reply to to customer email in order copy?

Tags: magento2, order-email

I would like to set the reply to address for order confirmation copy to the customer's email address.

I magento backend you can configure to send order confirmation copy as a separate email. Is there a way to set the reply to for the copy to the customer's email address?

Comment: I have a same question for Magento 1 as well. Have you figure out how to do it yet?